# Сохранение значений в полях формы после обновления страницы

Tags: php, html, kohana

На сайте есть форма добавления новостей, у формы есть валидация. Заполняю поля, потом нажимаю добавить новость. Срабатывает валидация, так как не все поля заполнены.
После того как страница перезагрузилась и вылезла валидация, всё, что писал в полях формы, сбросилось.

Как можно реализовать сохранение введённых данных?

Валидация сделана через модель. Пример:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'prname' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('min_length', array(':value', 10)),
            array('max_length', array(':value', 80))
        ),
        'shortdescription' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('min_length', array(':value', 80)),
            array('max_length', array(':value', 250))
        ),
    );
}

public function labels()
{
    return array(
        'prname' => 'Заголовок',
        'shortdescription' => 'Короткий текст',
        'description' => 'Полный текст',
    );
}
```

**Обновление**

Action.

```
public function action_add() {

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {     
    $data = Arr::extract($_POST, array('prname', 'istokssilk', 'istokname', 'date', 'time', 'shortdescription', 'description', 'prtitle', 'prkeys', 'prdes', 'prnamero', 'descriptionro', 'prtitlero', 'prkeysro', 'prdesro',
            'parent_id', 'category', 'block1', 'block2'));

  }

  $products = ORM::factory('product');
  $products->values($data);

  try {
    $products->save();
    $this->request->redirect('admin/products/edit/' . $products->pk());
  } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
    $errors = $e->errors('validation');
  }

  $cats = ORM::factory('category')->find_all();
  $adds = ORM::factory('add')->find_all();
  $content = View::factory('admin/product/v_product_add')
    ->bind('errors', $errors)
    ->bind('datacats', $datacats)
    ->bind('products', $products)
    ->bind('adds', $adds)
    ->bind('mats', $mats)
    ->bind('cats', $cats)
    ->bind('data', $data);

  $this->template->page_title = 'Добавить новость или статью';
  $this->template->content = ($content);

}
```

Comment: Валидацию все же лучше делать с помощью JS еще до отправки формы. Если же обязательно в php, то использовать ajax. Иначе посетители Вас просто не поймут.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую для этого куки, когда форма отправится, данные фильтруются, кладутся в куки на максимальный срок и потом валидируются. Если валидация не прошла, то виводим в поля формы, данные из куки. Это очень полезно для пользователя, когда он придет второй раз, поля будут уже заполнены.

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST)) {
     if(($_POST['email'] = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) !== false) {
         SetCookie("email", $_POST['email'],time()+31536000);
     }
}

$email = !empty($_COOKIE['email']) ? $_COOKIE['email'] : '';

?>

<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: У меня ошибку выдает: <input type="text" name="prname" value="<?php echo $prname; ?>" maxlength="80"/> я вот так сделал !  выдает ошибку на данное поле.

Comment: @ws17 Приведите кусок кода, где происходит инициализация переменной $pname.

Comment: Заспостил ниже, а ту сюда не влезало, если вы про акшион !

Comment: Я думаю нужно, просто для каждого типа поля, проверять значение из вашей ->bind('data', $data); и если оно есть и тип текстовый, то просто делаем <?php echo $data['pname']; ?>, если тип селект или чекбокс то делаем что то типа такого, <?php echo !empty($data['category_id']) ? ' selected=""' : ''; ?>, ну и для чекбокса selected заменить на checked. Или использовать что то типа Zend_Form, есть много опенсорсних библиотек для работы с формами.

Answer (score 0):

вариант "в лоб": при неудачной проверке возвращайте значения обратно в форму. она же у вас не на чистом html, а генерируется с помощью php?

Comment: Здравствуйте, нет там html там div в котором вставлены поля  импут, селект, и текстрейт.

Comment: генерация да через php, это же кохана.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое — это использовать такую структуру кода (схематично):

`page.php`:

```
    $formData=array('field1'=>value1, ...); // инициализация
    include('actions.php');

    if ($isError)
       echo $errorText; // сообщение об ошибке
    <form action="page.php"> ... </form> // заполняем форму значениями из массива $formData
```

`actions.php`:

```
    $isError=false;
    if (FORM_SUBMIT){
       $formData['field1'] = $_REQUEST['field1']; // получаем данные
       // Валидация значений $formData, при ошибке ставим флаг $isError=true и $errorText='текст ошибки';
       if($isError){
          return; // это ключевой момент! мы возвращаемся в page.php
       }else{ // все в порядке!
          // Запись в БД
          // передаем статус, можно также через сессию или куки
          header('location: page.php?status=ok');
          die;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение, но работает только для `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" name="prname" value="<?=@$_POST['prname']?>" />
```

Comment: Так это всё же решение (ответ), которое вас устраивает, или же это уточнение к вопросу?

Comment: Я нашел решение на input, нужно на селект и текстрайт

Answer (score -1):

Для select сделайте в цикле, сравнивая значения. Для опции, которая совпадает - вставьте атрибут selected.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Я не техническая поддержка, чтобы расписывать. Написал, как посчитал нужным.

Comment: На Stack Overflow приветствуются подробные развернутые ответы подкрепленные обоснованиями. Пожалуйста, помните, что главной целью ответа является помощь коллегам знаниями. Чем подробнее расписан ответ, тем выше вероятность, что он будет правильно понят, а как результат, полезен.

Comment: так будет ведь только для селекта, а как всю форму и то что в нее входит возвращать после перезагрузки.